# web.sitemap not found but it exists

Tags: asp.net, web.sitemap

I have an ASP.net site and I created a web.sitemap file in the root directory. It contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
<siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home" description="Rado Home" />
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Structural" description="">
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Doors" description=""/>
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Staircases" description=""/>
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Post Boxes" description=""/>
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="" title="Functional">
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Tables" />
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Features" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Sculpture">
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Wall" />
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Free Standing" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Smithing">
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Gold" />
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Silver" />
      <siteMapNode url="" title="Copper" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="~/About.aspx" title="About"/>
    <siteMapNode url="~/Contact.aspx" title="Contact"/>
  </siteMapNode>
 </siteMap>
```

I then created a menu in my master page as follows:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" Runat="server" />
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" />
```

When I run the site I get the following error:
The file web.sitemap required by XmlSiteMapProvider does not exist.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Is the root directory an Application Directory?

Comment: Yes it is an application directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Apparently there weren't enough permissions on the web.sitemap file so whichever user the site was running as couldn't read the file. On that note, does anyone know how I can find out which user the site accesses files as?

Comment: that depends on the platform. On XP it's aspnet, but on Win2003 & later (iis 6 & 7) you're looking for w3wp process run by networkservice.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It helps clearing that up. That's strange though because I gave Network Service full permissions to the site. Ah well, it works now :)

Comment: How did you add permissions to the user?

Comment: Right click on the file, go to properties and then Security where you can edit permissions

Answer (score 2):

Does your `web.config` contain a sitemap section?

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
    <add name="SiteMapDataSource1" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/MyApplication/Web.sitemap" />
    <add name="AdminSiteMap" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="/MyApplication/Admin.sitemap"  />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

like this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you call the sitemap you created web.sitemap?

If not, then you need to clear the providers in the sitemap tag & add a new provider that includes the name of your sitemap.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e333zt4.aspx) shows the default entry in the root web.config that you need to clear

Comment: Yes, it's called web.sitemap and there's nothing in the config file for sitemaps. I'm stumped...

Answer (score 0):

this issue can also occur if you have created a website copying it from another website but you forgot to create the related application into IIS